# Convex , then also Measurable

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I was reading about Jensen's inequality and noticed that don't require $\phi$ to be measurable here: [Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Measure-theoretic_and_probabilistic_form).

Therefore, I guess that being convex implies being measurable somehow, but I have never actually seen this and this is why I wanted to ask here if this is true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $f$ is convex then $\{f<\alpha\}$ is either empty or an interval, hence measurable.

(It's an interval because it's a convex set: if $f(x)<\alpha$ and $f(y)<\alpha$ then $f((1-\lambda)x+\lambda y)\le (1-\lambda)f(x)+\lambda f(y)<(1-\lambda)\alpha+\lambda\alpha=\alpha$.)

Comment: why should it be an interval? $f$ is not continuous.

Comment: @Lipschitz: Added a bit to clarify why it's an interval.